# Re partition using pyspark dataframe reducing the size of parquet

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I storing data in to parquet in S3 it is currently partitioned with columns

```
org_id, device_id, channel_id, source, col1, col2
```

I am using pyspark to read/ write parquet to se bucket.

partition columns are `[org_id, device_id, channel_id]`

Now i changed the partition as follows

```
[source, org_id, device_id, channel_id]
```

after changing the partition i have observed that size of the parquet reduce drastically
Original parquet was having size 220 mb after re-partition it become 7.5 mb

Now i am worried about data loss.

I tried df.count() method on original and post re-partition data 
it is giving equal number of row i.e 85000
Is this correct way to validate that data is intact
Is there any other way to verify this ?

Comment: Hi Chris, do you mean the entire size of the dataset drops to 7.5mb or each partition file in the source directory?

Comment: @AlexandrosBiratsis Yes..I did before and after record count it is equal so ..looks like adding the partition reduced the size. ...i will update if i find any other issue related data loss. so far looks good.